# Java: Problemas para entrar a un caso de un switch

Tags: java, condiciones

Cuando escribo el programa me pide que escriba la materia yo ingreso "Matematicas", el entra al caso uno y lo hace correctamente, pero cuando yo ingreso "Español", no entra al caso, no se cual es la razón agradecería la ayuda.
Lo que se me hace raro es que puedo ingresar al caso 1 sin ningún problema, pero al caso 2 no he podido.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class materias {
    public static String materia;
    public static double prom =0;
    public static double suma=0;
    public static double nota=0;
    public static void main (String []args){
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese la materia seleccionada: ");
        String materia = entrada.nextLine();
        switch (materia){
            case "Matematicas":
                System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de notas del alumno: ");
                double notasM= entrada.nextInt();
                for (int i =1; i<=notasM;i++){
                    System.out.println("ingrese nota"+" "+i+" "+"de"+" "+notasM+":");
                    nota = entrada.nextDouble();
                    suma+=nota;
                    System.out.println("La sumatoria de las notas es: "+ Math.round(suma));
                }
                prom = suma/nota;
                System.out.println("La nota final es: "+ prom);
                break;
            case "Español":
                System.out.println("Ingrese la cantidad de notas del alumno: ");
                double NotasE=entrada.nextInt();
                int contador=1;
                //while(contador<NotasE){
                System.out.println("ingrese nota"+" "+contador+" "+"de"+" "+NotasE+":");
                nota=entrada.nextDouble();
                suma+=nota;
                contador++;
                System.out.println("La sumatoria de las notas es: "+Math.round(suma));
                prom=suma/nota;
                System.out.println("La nota final es: "+ prom);
                //}
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Muy probablemente el problema sea en como se comparan las cadenas.. pero igual, no deberias usar un case para esto, ya que todos tus casos hacen lo mismo.... no?

Comment: Es que asi lo han pedido en cada case, debe realizar el promedio de notas de diferente forma mediante un for un while y un do while

Comment: yo no veo ninguna iteracion ahi.. veo un case, que no tiene nada que ver....

Comment: En el primer case hace el promedio de notas mediante un for y eso lo hace correctamente, lo que sucede es que en el segundo case, ni siquiera entra, es decir yo ingreso "Español", y no entra al segundo case, he comentado el ciclo while dentro del segundo case para mirar si era eso pero nada. Cabe aclarar que en el segundo case cuando ingrese español debe realizar el promedio de notas pero esta vez mediante un ciclo while

Comment: **Observaciones:** 1.- Sí entra a tu case. Así como está tu código entra al case "Español", lo que puedes ver porque imprime la instrucción de ingresar nota 1 de n. 2.- ¿Para qué usas un *case* si siempre se va a ejecutar el mismo código? (por lo que veo quieres hacer lo mismo en los dos casos). Recuerda que estas estructuras se utilizan cuando se pueden tomar dos o más caminos distintos.

Answer (score 0):

probablemente es la letra "ñ", ya que debe pasar algo al comprar los strings y siempre jode el UTF-8 en los casos de caracteres especiales.

Intenta cambiar el case por otra cosa que no tenga esos caracteres y me cuentas.

Saludos!

Comment: Al parecer al declarar case "Lenguaje" en lugar de case "Español"
Es decir ingreso por pantalla lenguaje y en el case cambio Español por lenguaje.
Ya entra al siguiente case, no se por que razón será

Comment: la ñ al comparar cadenas?

Comment: lo cambiare por Espanol, gracias

Comment: No.. deberias entender porque el switch funciona mal con cadenas.. nadie va a escribir espanol....

Comment: La realidad es que no reconoce la letra ñ, ya he probado, con otras palabras que lleven esta letra y pasa igual, he decidido poner mientras tanto lenguaje en vez de español para poder continuar

Comment: No es problema de la ñ. Acabo de hacer la prueba en Java y funciona correctamente

Comment: efectivamente era eso, gracias

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.